# Azure Dev Ops Search Capability Limited Compared to TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We've just moved from on-premise TFS 2019 to a local install of Azure Dev Ops. The upgrade has gone well, but the search functionality in Azure Dev Ops is VERY limited.

Whereas in TFS 2019 I could use search to filter by any field and use operators like `NOT` or `AND`, the available fields in Azure Dev Ops is limited to just `Assigned To`, `Created By`, `State` or `Work Item Type`. The 'classic' search results panel also allowed me to filter by work item type, state, project but all of that has gone too. Azure Dev Ops just seems to create a query, which I then need to amend to filter by project/type/state etc...

This is all I see at the moment:

[image]

How do I configure Azure Dev Ops so that it will allow searching across any field? Can I restore the previous search functionality?

Comment: Cn you share some screenshots of where you're searching? And does the Azure DevOps installation have Search enabled (Elastic Search) and has it been successfully upgraded to match the Azure DevOps Server version? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops-2020&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#upgrading-search

Comment: Screenshot added. I've asked our IT team to check the state of ElasticSearch. I'll report back.

Comment: My guess would be that ES is currently not configured correctly or turned off.

Comment: Ok, we'll have a look at that tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Azure DevOps Server Administration Console, to check whether the Search is configured.
2. If the Search is configured, [Check indexing status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops-2020#check-indexing-status-for-tfs-2017-update-1-and-later-and-azure-devops-server) for the collection.
3. If the status is normal, [reindex the repository or collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops-2020#reindex-a-repository-or-collection) where the files are located.

Comment: How's your issue going? Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Elastic Search wasn't configured.